# Custom XSL – formatting the date column in ItemStyle.xsl

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part, date-time, item-styles

I have a Content Query Web Part in which I am displaying the data from a Blog sub-site.

The **Item Style** being used is "Title and description". Title displays the title of the document. For the Description, I have given a site column **Published**, which is of type 'Date and Time'.

- Title
- 2015-11-23 10:20:00

However, the **Published** date is given in the American format (see above). I need the short UK date format, i.e. “23 November 2015”.

In an attempt to resolve this I **[followed this tutorial here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl.aspx)**, which suggests using custom XSL.

Unfortunately I can’t get this to work. What I have done so far is this...

1. In the **ItemStyle.xsl** stylesheet, I added the following line at the top as instructed:
   **xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"**
2. I then added in the FormatDate line (i.e. the second line down):

[image]

3. These changes were then saved and published.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong please? Am I putting the FormatDate line in the wrong place?